# Excel cell value change depending on other cell value

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to achieve is this:
Cell F1 can contain values "MT", "LT" or "MT+LT". If I change the value to "MT", cells C10:C15 should change to value 0. If I change value to LT, cells C3:C8 should change to 0. This looks like a simple task, but I can't find an example, how to do it. 
I'm new to VBA so please be gentle :)

Comment: what if `F1` = "MT+LT"?

Comment: In that case nothing has to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code (you have to paste it in desired sheet in VBE). It will be fired on every change in the sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'if value changed in some other cell than F1, then finish Sub
    If Target.Address <> "$F$1" Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = "MT" Then
        Range("C10:C15").Value = 0
    ElseIf Target.Value = "LT" Then
        Range("C3:C8").Value = 0
    ElseIf Target.Value = "MT+LT" Then
        'some action, you seem to forgot
    End If

End Sub
```